# Convert AdBlock Plus block list to some Opera's ad blocking mechanism/add-on format

Tags: firefox, opera, adblock

I'm using a whole bunch of myself-written blocking rules for AdBlock Plus in Firefox (they are not overly complicated; new versions of ABP provide quite advanced syntax, but I'm not using it much).

I sometimes use Opera though. There's built-in blocking mechanism in Opera and there are also third-party add-ons to do so.

I want to export my Firefox block list to Opera (whatever it's ad-blocker).

Is there any tool available capable of doing so? I've googled around a bit, but without success.

Finally, I could think of writing such tool by myself, but this requires some time to learn Opera's adblocking syntax and the time to write the tool, so I want to avoid it and not reinvent the wheel if there's such tool available somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

[From Fanboy's Adblock Forum](http://forums.fanboy.co.nz/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5141):

> a perl script that generates Opera urlfilter and CSS filter from ABP list

Make sure to read the entire discussion to get the latest version and know about possible issues.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look when I have some spare time in a couple of days.